# I want to display list of users and show their respective data through graph

Tags: angular, typescript

I am displaying a list of users, where each user has a show button. On click i want to show data through graphs for that respective user. I have written a toggle logic, that works fine ,but if i click the button on first user and then on second  , rather than showing data for second user,it hides the previous graph but does not show any data for current row.

toggle logic (user.component.ts)

```
toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    if (this.visible) {
      console.log('enter');
      this.show.emit(this.visible);
    } else {
      this.show.emit(null);
    }
  }
```

user list html code

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">city</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users,index as i" >

          <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.city }}</td>
          <td><button id= "i" class="btn btn-success" (click)= "toggle()">show</button></td>
         </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Graph

```
rating: Rating[] = [];
   @Input() flag = false;


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init');
    var myChart= new Chart('myChart', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Technical', 'Communication', 'Experience', 'Leadership'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'skill scores',
              data: [10,15, 16, 22],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'

              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'

              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
  }
```

Graph html

```
<div style="height:40%;width:40%;" class="center" [hidden] ="!flag" >
  <canvas
  class="chart chart-bar"
  chart-data="dataChart" id  = "myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

true and null is passed to graph component which shows the graph based on passed values. On debugging i found that it is because , there is one common toggle function for all users. But could not figure out a way to implement toggle functionality for each user separately . Hope I am clear, Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to change your boolean `isVisible` to the id of the user instead:
`visibleUserId?: number`

Your toggle function would be something like:

```
toggle(id: number) {
    this.visibleUserId = id === this.visibleUserId ? null : id;
    this.show.emit(this.visibleUserId);
  }
```

and in the markup:

```
<button id= "i" class="btn btn-success" (click)= "toggle(user.id)">show</button>
```

Now you now that when there is an id being emitted on the `Output() show`, that's the id of a user that you should show a graph for. If it's null, then you should show no graph.